# How do I replace an absolute path in XQUERY?

Tags: xquery, idm

I'm trying to replace the current query, which retrieves a logo from my IDM database, with a new query that uses the customer number from my XML instead.

###### Current query:

```
{
   "xpath": null,
   "hide": null,
   "image": {
        "xqueries": [
          "/ZZ_Etailer_Logo[@Customer=\"GREE73\"]"
        ]
      }
    }
```

###### New query:

```
    {
      "xpath": null,
      "hide": null,
      "image": {
        "xqueries": [
          "/ZZ_Et
ailer_Logo[@Customer=\"{/M3OutDocument/DataArea/Document/DocumentHeader/OQCONA}\"]"
     ]
   }
}
```

I was hoping that using `OQCONA` (customer number) would retrieve the correct logo, but it's not returning anything. What am I doing wrong?

The original query works, but it only retrieves one logo, which is not suitable. I don't want to create multiple documents to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you give more detail about the technology you are using? This doesn't look like XQuery to me, and I don't know what the "idm" tag means. Whatever technology it is, I doubt that nesting double-quotes within double-quotes is going to work.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for the reply.  I'm using INFOR IDM which uses microsoft word along with a plug in to create documents. Maybe this is a tailored xquery version ?

Comment: I suspect the issue is with the nested quotes, but I'm only guessing.